# Get the nodes/pods information using cluster name or context name when we have multiple configs

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm trying to fetch nodes list via ansible playbook using a context name. but its not working

my playbook:

getnodes.yaml

```
- name: "get nodes"
  hosts: kubernetes
  tasks:
    - name: "nodes"
      command: "kubectl get nodes --context='contextname'"
```

I do have multiple clusters in config file. I need to either specify cluster name or context name and get the nodes list or to perform any activity  on a particular cluster

Comment: What error are you getting? Does your ansible script is aware of the location of kubeconfig with those cluster definitions?

Comment: As far as I understand you when you run the command `kubectl get nodes --context='contextname'` directly on your master node, everything works fine, right ? And it fails only when you run it as a part of your ansible playbook against the master node ? What errors do you get ?

Comment: "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: @mario Yes that's correct. i'm able to execute from command line
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: @user, are you sure it is on the same host as you run your ansible playbook ?

Comment: @mario, Yes it's on the same host.
My scenario is, I do have 3 different clusters. My config file is on a jump box which  includes context and cluster names for 3 different clusters. from my jump box I can execute kubectl get nodes or can do any other operation.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by jump box ? How do you usually connect to it ? It looks only like an issue with ansible not being able to properly ssh to it ans issue the `kubectl` command.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you when you run the command `kubectl get nodes --context='contextname'` directly on your master node, everything works fine, right ? And it fails only when you run it as a part of your ansible playbook against the master node ? What errors do you get ?

> Yes that's correct. i'm able to execute from command line
>
> "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
>   specify the right host or port?"

Are you sure it is available on the same host as you run your ansible playbook ? I mean your **Kubernetes master node**, on which you have `kubectl` binary installed ? My guess is that it is not and even if it is on the same host you'll not be able to connect to it using `localhost:8080`.

Look. You're not using here any particular **Ansible module** specific to manage **Kubernetes** cluster like [this one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#k8s-raw-module), which you run directly against the API server and you need to provide its valid URL. Instead here you are just using simple `command` module which doesn't care what command you want to run as long as you provide a valid `hostname` with **ssh access** and **Python installed**.

In this case your **Ansible** simply tries to ssh to your **Kubernetes master node** and execute the shell command you passed to it:

```
kubectl get nodes --context='contextname'
```

I really doubt that your ssh server listens on port 8080.
If you run your ansible playbook on same host you can run your `kubectl` commands there are much easier solutions in **Ansible** for such cases like:

`local_action` or `delegate_to: localhost` statements in your task or more globally `connection: local`
More details on usage of all above mentioned statements in your Ansible `plays` you can find in [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) and in [this](http://willthames.github.io/2018/07/01/connection-local-vs-delegate_to-localhost.html) article.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you.. Even when I use the module delegate_to  it gives the same error. "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: Could you post your playbook yaml content ? Additionally check the content of the inventory file. You must've defined somewhere such port. Ansible tries to connect to it for some reason. You may try to grep your ansible project files for `8080` to find out where this port is defined.